# Bad Interpreter: No such file or directory error when launching iPython with Anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, pythonpath, bash

My ipython was working fine until I installed a new IDE and accidentally changed some path settings. Now, when I try to launch ipython from terminal I get:

```
-bash: /Users/JohnSmith/anaconda/bin/ipython: /Users/JohnSmith/anaconda/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How do I change my path/local environment settings back so that it works?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that uninstalling and re-installing Anaconda was the easiest solution (after several hours of playing around with my PATH variables, etc).

Comment: Although I appreciate the solution, it is an awful solution!  I will do the same as you and spend time trying to avoid this - probably to come to the same conclusion as you.  OSS i tell you...

Answer (score 0):

This github thread shows the solution from spyder dev [ccordoba12](https://github.com/ccordoba12):
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/9951#issuecomment-517913824

run

```
conda install -f python.app
```

(Very fast to run)

Then spyder etc. was fixed.  Apparently an incorrect python path in the launch script.

FYI I had this same issue with Anaconda install with python 3.8 (2022), after a big mess with upgrading anaconda via `conda update --all`.  On MacBook Pro (Intel)