# Ubuntu anaconda paths messed up after drive switch

Tags: ubuntu, path, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

quick background: I have 2 harddrives, and i recently switched the other one from /media/waffleboy/storage to /storage. This drive is where anaconda is installed on. I realise the paths are screwed right now, with any command giving me the following error:

```
zsh: /storage/Programfiles/anaconda3/bin/spyder: bad interpreter: /media/waffleboy/Storage/Programfiles/anaconda3/bin/python: no such file or directory
```

I could not find where the paths were located online (no ~/.profile folder and its not in ~/.config either). How should i fix this to get it working again?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after more intensive googling, there is no hope for this problem as anaconda is not meant to be moved after installation. A warning for people who move their hard drive paths to diff mount points.

[Bad Interpreter: No such file or directory error when launching iPython with Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530084/bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-launching-ipython-with-ana)

Reinstalling from scratch now.